# How to get select menu session data in another page laravel 8

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I can successfully get input session data on another page but I can't get select menu selected data in another page.

**This is my first form**

```html
<form action="{{ route('admin.create.step.one.post') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf

    <label for=""> Student Name </label>
    <input type="text" name="student_name" value="{{ $report->student_name ?? '' }}">
    <br>

    <label for=""> Email </label>
    <input type="text" name="student_email" value="{{ $report->student_email ?? '' }}">
    <br>

    <label for=""> Phone number </label>
    <input type="text" name="student_phone" value="{{ $report->student_phone ?? '' }}">

    <label for=""> Group </label>
    <select name="group" id="">
        <option value="1" {{ $report->group ?? '' }}> Science </option>
        <option value="2" {{ $report->group ?? '' }}> Arts </option>
    </select>

    <button type="submit"> Preview </button>

</form>
```

**I want to get session data in this page**.

I can't get select menu session data.

```html
<form action="">
    @csrf
    <table>

        <td> {{ $report->student_name }} </td>
        <td> {{ $report->student_email }} </td>
        <td> {{ $report->student_phone }} </td>
        <td> {{ $report->group }} </td>

    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood from your question you want to select the item within your select input.

You are just missing this line:

```php
{{ $report->group == 1 ? 'selected' :'' }}
```

```php
<form action="{{route('admin.create.step.one.post')}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <label for="student_name">Student Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="student_name" id="student_name" value="{{ $report->student_name}}">
    <br>
    <label for="student_email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="student_email" id="student_email" value="{{ $report->student_email}}">
    <br>
    <label for="student_phone">Phone number</label>
    <input type="text" name="student_phone" id="student_phone" value="{{ $report->student_phone}}">
    <br>
    <label for="group">Group</label>
    <select name="group" id="group">
        <option value="1" {{ $report->group == 1 ? 'selected' :'' }}>Science</option>
        <option value="2" {{ $report->group == 2 ? 'selected' :'' }}>Arts</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Preview</button>
</form>
```

Now, if you need are storing in the session() something and not getting it please update your question with your Controller and I will update my answer to help you further.

Comment: When I try ```{{ $report->group == 1 ? 'selected' :'' }}```, I get Trying to get property 'group' of non-object

Comment: Can you show me How Can I get Dropdown menu session data and how I can I show it?

Comment: Yes for sure Amijanina, I can help you but please check out Wael's answer as he mentioned you can use `old('group')` if that didn't help you let me know and I will update my answer :) so you can use both session old value & the DB value as well, or if you wish you can really stored in session using `session()->put('group', yourValueHere)` and retrieve it using `session()->get('group')`.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to get the selected item when you submitted and an error appeared so if you want to get the old value
you can do so using `old()` method in your blade.

```php
{{ old('group') == 1 ? 'selected' :'' }}
```

```php
<form action="{{route('admin.create.step.one.post')}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <label for="student_name">Student Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="student_name" id="student_name" value="{{ $report->student_name}}">
    <br>
    <label for="student_email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="student_email" id="student_email" value="{{ $report->student_email}}">
    <br>
    <label for="student_phone">Phone number</label>
    <input type="text" name="student_phone" id="student_phone" value="{{ $report->student_phone}}">
    <br>
    <label for="group">Group</label>
    <select name="group" id="group">
        <option value="1" {{ old('group') == 1 ? 'selected' :'' }}>Science</option>
        <option value="2" {{ old('group') == 2 ? 'selected' :'' }}>Arts</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Preview</button>
</form>
```